# How to compare two different dataframes(xlsx) and extract equal data in Rstudio

Tags: r, excel, merge

I have two spreadsheets, the first in which I have a destination and a quantity to be trasported and a second in which there is the destination and for each range of quantity a cost of transport.

How it be possible to extract from the first spreadsheet one row, compare it with the second spreadsheet and find the same destination the right range and print the cost of transport?!

This is what I have done to upload spreadsheet:

```
library(openxlsx)
openxlsx::read.xlsx()
library(raster)
library(ggmap)
for(i in 1:14)
  {
  mat<-read.xlsx("C:/Users/Caterina/Dropbox/progetti lean/progetto data analytics/Cost_world.xlsx", sheet = i)
  mat
}

matr<-read.xlsx("C:/Users/Caterina/Dropbox/progetti lean/progetto data analytics/transport.xlsx")
matr
matr<-as.data.frame(matr)
if(y<- matr$NAZIONE==mat$Nazione
)
matr$NAZIONE[y]
```

Comment: Is this related to the SQL language?

Comment: i'm using Rstudio but i'm looking for a query to extract data and compare them with other database

Comment: These are spreadsheets not databases. You are loading in two tables called mat and matr probably structured as data frames. If they have common fields, NAZIONE and Nazione I think? Then you can use merge to combine the tables. See ?merge for details.

Comment: yes you are totally right I mean Data frames... but I already tried with "merge" but it doesn't work for our needs!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to merge to tables, ensure that you have desired columns with a common name, including capitalization i.e. small and big letters.

Here is working a merge with a common column name:

```
> a = matrix(1:4,2,2)
> colnames(a) <- c("A","B")
> a
     A B
[1,] 1 3
[2,] 2 4
> b = matrix(c(1:2,5:6),2,2)
> colnames(b) <- c("A","C")
> b
     A C
[1,] 1 5
[2,] 2 6
> merge(a,b)
  A B C
1 1 3 5
2 2 4 6
```

But if the case of variable names does not match, then `merge(...)` does not merge by columns `A` and `a`:

```
> colnames(b) <- c("a","C")
> merge(a,b)
  A B a C
1 1 3 1 5
2 2 4 1 5
3 1 3 2 6
4 2 4 2 6
```

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer but this solution is similar to use a cbind or and rbind wright? My purpose is for example: identify the content in a cell under a certain column (italy, under column nation) and then search "italy" in all the cells of another excel file and give all the row in which "italy" is present.